# Jquery prepopulate data return null although data-pre html tag has expected values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, jquery-tokeninput

I am using [Jquery token input plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) to for autocomplete and `prepopulating data.`
Autocomplete looks fine, but I do have some problems with prepopulating data.

This is my javascript:

```
tokenOptions = {
    theme: 'facebook',
    searchingText: null,
    hintText: null,
    noResultsText: null,
    allowFreeTagging: true,
    tokenValue: 'name',
    searchDelay: 1000,
    prePopulate: $('#citizen_profile_attributes_city').data('pre')

}

$(document).ready ->

  console.log('prepopulate:' + tokenOptions.prePopulate)


  $("#citizen_profile_attributes_city").tokenInput("/cities.json",
    tokenOptions )
```

This is a part of form(in HAML):

```
 = f.text_field :city, :data  => { 'pre' => @profile.pre_populate_city } , :id => 'citizen_profile_attributes_city'
```

This is method pre_populate_city:

```
  def pre_populate_city
    city_name   = self.city
    city_id      = (City.find_by_name city_name).id
    { "id" => city_id, "name" => city_name}.to_json
  end
```

This is returned html:

[image]

As you can see, in html there a data attribute with correct values, but I do not see them in prepopulated area.

In my javascript I used **console log** to see the output, it return null, when I try to query this id in console, I do get desired attributes:

[image]

The question is  - what is wrong with this code ?

**Note:** I do tried to change id in jquery for `#token-input-citizen_profile_attributes_city` as well.

**EDIT** 
After wrapping and object into array, pre populating works, but it prepopulates with undefined:

[image]

[image]

```
  def pre_populate_city
    city_name   = self.city
    city_id      = (City.find_by_name city_name).id
    [{ "id" => city_id, "name" => city_name}.to_json]
  end
```

**EDIT2** [image]

parsing prepopulate with $.parseJSON does not help:

[image]

**EDIT3**

console log with $.parseJSON
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues with the original code.

1. Prepopulation must always be done with a JSON *array*, not just an object as originally used.
2. The second issue was with the encoding of resultant encoding of the JSON in the `data-pre` attribute. The JSON must be HTML encoded, that is, quotation marks replaced with `&quot;`.

For clarification, this is what the `data-pre` attribute should look like in the above situation, I image rails has some method to automatically html encode strings.

```
data-pre="[{&quot;id&quot;:2368,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Tokajík&quot;}]"
```

The [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdzvP/5/) shows a fully working version. Note that the data does not need to be JSON-parsed as previously suggested in comments, my mistake. Hope this helps!